# How do I fix this NoReverseMatch in Django?

Tags: python, django

Edit: this question is different from [django 1.8 NoReverseMatch at error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720413/django-1-8-noreversematch-at-error) because this one specifically asks how to do it with the ModelViewSet class

I'm trying to make a blog post/facebook wall type app and am getting a NoReverseMatch Error in Django. It happens after trying to submit the post form.

Here's my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from wall.models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    return render(request, 'wall/index.html', {'form': form})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'wall/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^post_detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The error page says

```
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 5}' not found
1 pattern(s) tried: ['$post_detail/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it) already, but none of the suggestions help. My regex and url names are all spelled correctly.

How do I fix this error?

Here is my base urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('wall.urls'), name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/complete/$', views.registration_complete, name='registration_complete'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', views.logged_in, name='loggedin'),
]
```

Comment: Is your error message appearing after form submit ?

Comment: @Lindow yes, I'll add that in the question.

Comment: Then take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is on the redirect after the form submission, change

```
return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```

to

```
return redirect(reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': post.pk}))
```

(to import reverse use : `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`)

---

As Alasdair pointed out, a `$` on include was also missing from your base urls.py

Comment: No, I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have the ability to enter the created page by the url or is it still a problem on form submit ?

Comment: It says page not found. I tried both http://127.0.01:8000/post_detail and http://127.0.01:8000/post_detail/1 (a made up primary key)

Comment: These type of errors can be for multiple reasons, try adding `/` at the end of your url just like that : `127.0.01:8000/post_detail/1/`, does it work ? (the url you're trying to access has to exist otherwise it'll return a 404)

Comment: It gives me the same error

Comment: What happen if you replace `post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)` by `post = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk) ` ? Could you also include your base urls.py file ?

Comment: That didn't work either, same error.

Comment: Have you restarted your server ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146696/discussion-between-matthew-drill-and-lindow).

Comment: You don't need to use `reverse` with `redirect`. The advantage of using the `redirect` shortcut here is that it's simpler than `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you have a dollar in your regex when you include your app's urls. Remove it.

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work? If you have removed the dollar from the include then that should fix the error. Make sure you have restarted your server.

Comment: I removed the $ from the url pattern and I restarted the server. What do you mean by removing it from the include?

Comment: @MatthewDrill He meant to remove the $ from include on your base urls.py, can you show the file to us ?

Comment: It sounds like you remove the dollar from the wrong place. See the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720413/django-1-8-noreversematch-at-error) for an example.